# directory name too long pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I tried to create a file using Oracle UTL_FILE.FOPEN command but i get this error.
Is there an alternative?

```
log_file:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN("P:\Documentation\Project Team\SA\CSR_Documentation\SHR-10500",'outputforDeleteStudentGroup.txt', 'W');
```

I dont want to say create or replace directory because the directory already exists.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY` does not create a directory at the operating system level.  It creates an Oracle directory object.  You want to create an Oracle directory object that points to a directory at the operating system level.  You could potentially go with the very old-school approach of modifying the `UTL_FILE_DIR` initialization parameter to include `P:\Documentation\Project Team\SA\CSR_Documentation\SHR-10500` and reboot the database but that is not something that I would recommend.

The first parameter to `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` should be a string which means that it should be enclosed in single quotes not double quotes.

Is the `P:\` drive something that exists on the database server's file system?  Or is it a network drive that gets mounted by the database server?  Or is it a directory that is available to the client?

Comment: It is on a network and at the same place from where i read my sql script. Hey also when i give single quotes it says invalid path. Why am i not able to access the file and idea?

Comment: @sriram - You can only use physical paths rather than Oracle directory objects in `UTL_FILE` if the path is in your databases's `UTL_FILE_DIR` parameter.  But `UTL_FILE_DIR` is depricated in favor of using Oracle directory objects.  I'm still not sure if you are saying that the `P:\` drive is mounted on the database server's file system or if it is just something that is mounted by the client.  `UTL_FILE` cannot reference directories that are available to the client's file system just those that are part of the server's file system.

Comment: @Dave Is there any command by which i know where the database servers file system is. What do you mean by mounted by the client? sorry i am a newbie to oracle.

Comment: @sriram - The database server's file system is the set of directories that are visible to the operating system on the server where Oracle happens to be installed.  It has nothing to do with Oracle.  Do you have an operating system login to the server(s) where Oracle is running?

Comment: @Dave It is mounted to the client on a windows.No i dont have a operating system login to the servers.

Comment: @sriram - `UTL_FILE`, as with all PL/SQL code, runs on the database server.  It can only access files that are available on the database server.  It cannot access files that are merely available to the client machine.